# Expand and position absolutely positioned div to relatively positioned parent

Tags: html, css, position

Many questions have been asked answered about similar topics, but I couldn't find the exact answer to this question anywhere.  Also, given that it's 2018, I'm wondering if there are any new methods to achieve what I'm looking for.

Basically, I have a `<div>` that has content that exceeds the height, thus will need to scroll.  Within that `<div>` is a waiting, or loading modal that covers it while downloading new data.  It works fine, unless the user scrolls down, and the absolutely positioned div, at 100%, is pinned to the top of the content.

I've tried using `top` and `bottom` and multiple `position` and `display` variations for both the parent and the child, to no luck.

The following is a jsfiddle with all of the associated code: https://jsfiddle.net/wmu7ghmm/2/.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, sir, for being the first question I have seen today that was written in proper English and presented an actual problem rather than vague conundrums.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/o2jcdL2L/!

Comment: @TftW: thanks, buy your solution works only if the user hasn't already scrolled down.

Comment: Hang on a minute...

Comment: If you don't mind them being jumped back up to the top: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/o2jcdL2L/1/

Comment: If you do, hang on another minute...

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd love to see what you come up with without having to scroll to the top, but the reality is, your `scrollTo({top:0}` version works perfectly for my needs.  Happy to mark it as the answer if you want to post it.

Comment: Got it, without the jumping to the top. (I had to transfer it to a function, it was getting too unwieldy to have in an onclick attribute.)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/o2jcdL2L/4/

Comment: And cleaned up a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/o2jcdL2L/5/

Comment: I'm not complaining because you've already helped me out, but your latest version actually put the modal below the top of the div on my browser.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot?

Comment: Hmmm, now that you've asked for proof, it seems to be working fine.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the user scroll to the top.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
 <div id="wait-modal" class="waiting" style="display:none"></div>

  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  <p>This is a bunch of text, over and over again.<p>
  </div>

 <br>

 <button onclick="document.getElementById('wait-modal').style.display='block';document.getElementById('container').classList.add('no-scroll');document.getElementById('container').scrollTo({top:0})">
   Load Data
 </button>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  max-height:300px;  
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background-color:#dedede;
  position:relative;
}
.container.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.waiting {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;

  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition:background-color 250ms ease;


}

.waiting:hover {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  transition:background-color 250ms ease;
}
.waiting:after {
  content:'PLEASE WAIT...';
  font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: This suits my needs just fine, thanks @TricksfortheWeb

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I'm still working on the other way, though. It's a bit of a challenge, and I can't resist one of those :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take it out of the container and position it absolute over it with the exact same dimensions as the container.

```
.waiting {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  max-height:300px;  
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;

  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition:background-color 250ms ease; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmu7ghmm/4/

Comment: Unfortunately because your solution uses fixed widths and heights, it doesn't work for me.  I need something more dynamic and response.

Comment: @pshep123 well, your snippet used fixed widths and heights, that's why I took that route. Are you gonna use flex ? I kinda like the challenge

Comment: The snippet used fixed widths and heights for the container, but note that the `.waiting` class was using percentages.  And I'm definitely open to using flex.  Looking forward to seeing what you come up with, thanks!